# DataStax Opscenter do not sees remote agents (windows)

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0, datastax, opscenter

I am new to Cassandra.

I'm trying to deploy a test environment.

> Win server 2012 (192.168.128.71)  -> seed node
>
> Win server 2008 (192.168.128.70)  -> simple node
>
> Win server 2008 (192.168.128.69)  -> simple node

On all nodes, I installed the same version Cassandra (2.0.9 from Datastax). 
Disabled windows firewall.

The cluster Ring formed. But on each node I see
Test Cluster  (Cassandra 2.0.9) **1 of 3 agents connected**

Node does not see the Remote Agent. On each PC, the agent service is running.

In file `datastax_opscenter_agent-stderr`, I see the following line

> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
>
> log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [log4j.properties].

Please tell me the possible cause how can I diagnose.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Brian, could you show the agent logs from all the nodes (not the -stderr ones?)
Also which machine runs opscenterd, i.e. which address you use to open the OpsCenter UI?

Comment: Yes, of course. Server 192.168.128.71 should be seed. The archive logs from two servers http://1drv.ms/1BiKsdi

Comment: In the archive I see opscenterd logs on both of the machines. Can you verify that opscenterd (the python process) runs only on one of the machines? Also adding `stomp_interface: 192.168.128.71` to the agent’s address.yaml on all machines might help.

Comment: Arre, thank you so much! You moved me forward. Please publish your post, so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Really do not see the running of services opscenterd.
Each machine is now running 3 service: (DataStax_OpsCenter_Community, DataStax_OpsCenter_Agent, DataStax_Cassandra_Community_Server). How exactly  to run opscenterd?

Comment: DataStax_OpsCenter_Community is the opscenterd one, it should only be run on one machine.

Comment: If it will be useful, updated log file   http://1drv.ms/1pDmX9u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have OpsCenter server running on all machines in the cluster. Agents connect to the local OpsCenter servers, so when you open the UI for one of them, you only see one agent connected.

To fix this, stop the server processes (DataStax_OpsCenter_Community) on all machines except for one, and add `stomp_interface: <server-ip>` to the `address.yaml` for the agents on all machines, then restart the agents.